# Get an index of array and remove everything left of that index

Tags: c#, arrays, int

I have an array of `int`s

```
int[] RowOfints = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;
```

if i enter for example value `4` i want to remove `1,2,3` from array and return what's left.
How to do that?

Comment: Why are you removing 1,2,3 because of the value 4? Is it their value or their position?

Comment: @Jeffrey i dont think it makes really difference when he has a sequential array, sir.

Comment: @EmreVeriyaz - True, but is the array sequence an invarient or is it just an example? If it is always a sequential list, then there is not really a good reason to even store it in an array to begin with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interpreting your question that you want to find the index for the value `4` and then take everything starting from that index position.

```
var result = RowOfInts.SkipWhile(item => item != 4); // optionally, .ToArray()
```

`result` will be an `IEnumerable<int>` consisting of `4 .. 9`. If you want a concrete array, you can use the optional `ToArray()` extension method as well. If no elements in the array match the given criteria, you will get a zero-length sequence.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram This will do. 1 more question, can i make selection of numbers
For example of that array to displa values only between 4 and 7

Comment: @Michael, that sounds like a `Where` filter. `RowOfInts.Where(item => item >= 4 && item <= 7);` This would return anything meeting that criteria regardless of its position within the original sequence. You can also chain these methods to filter, group, order, and/or project your data in any number of ways. Based upon your questions phrasing, you can see that there were a lot of interpretations of what you actually wanted!

Comment: These LINQ methods I'm showing do not mutate the original array. It still exists in its original condition.

Comment: What to do if the number of elements are unknown?
if for ex. number are loaded from a txt file.
i can display loaded ints from file.

Comment: @Michael27 if you can ensure they will be sequential I think you can use my code, if they are not sequential it needs some modifications.

Comment: @Michael, LINQ methods are not specifically for arrays. They support `IEnumerable<T>`, which simply represent a sequence of elements of type `T`. If you have anything specific to ask regarding another scenario, I would suggest a new question.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use LINQ:

```
int[] newRowOfInts = new int[RowOfInts.Length - index];
Array.Copy(RowOfInts, index, newRowOfInts, 0, newRowOfInts.Length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) extension in LINQ.

```
int[] newArray = RowOfInts.Skip(value).ToArray();
```

Comment: Skip(2) skips first 2 elements in sequence. That is not what OP asked. Hmm, or, it is. Depends on interpretation.

Comment: He just needs to skip `value - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, now that I understand the question better, I will post my version of the actual requirements (again perversely emphasising effeciency over readability):

```
private static int[] RemoveBeforeValue(int[] source, int value)
{
    if (source == null)
        return null;
    int valueIndex = 0;
    while (valueIndex < source.Length && source[valueIndex] != value)
        valueIndex++;
    if (valueIndex == 0)
        return source;
    int[] result = new int[source.Length - valueIndex];
    Array.Copy(source, valueIndex, result, 0, result.Length);
    return result;
}
```

**OLD ANSWER**

If you want to do it the hard (but efficient!) way, then you can do this (assuming you want to remove values less than the supplied value):

```
private static int[] RemoveValuesLessThan(int[] source, int newMinimum)
{
    if (source == null)
        return null;
    int lessThanCount = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < source.Length; index++)
        if (source[index] < newMinimum)
            lessThanCount++;
    if (lessThanCount == 0)
        return source;
    int[] result = new int[source.Length - lessThanCount];
    int targetIndex = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < source.Length; index++)
        if (source[index] >= newMinimum)
            result[targetIndex++] = source[index];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code for what amounts to `source.Where(item => item >= newMinimum).ToArray()`, isn't it?

Comment: @Anthony Pegram - It a lot of source code, but it's actaully *doing* a whole lot less than your version. Yeah, yours is probably better, but I like to micro-optimize everything to death.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram - It’s funny that no one has posted your LINQ version as the answer yet. I really thought my interpretation of the question was the most likely, and your code is the most obvious implementation of the answer.

Comment: what do you think about my code sir, I want some comments from you to develop myself

Answer (score 0):

[image: output]
For a sequential array of ints

```
public static void RemoveIntsBefore(int i) 
    {
        int[] RowOfints = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

        for (int k = 0; k < RowOfints.Length; k++)
        {
            if (RowOfints.ElementAt(k) < i)
            {
                RowOfints[k] = i;
            }
        }

        RowOfints = RowOfints.Distinct().ToArray();
//this part is to write it on console
            //foreach (var item in RowOfints)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine(item);
            //}

            //Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

with this one your array does not have to be sequential

```
public static void RemoveIntsBefore(int i) 
    {
        int[] RowOfints = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1,2 };                     

        Console.WriteLine("OUTPUT");
        foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(i-1, RowOfints.Length + 1 - i).ToArray())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(RowOfints[item]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: Your answer says "without using any temp array or LINQ", yet your code includes `Distinct().ToArray()`, both of which are indeed part of LINQ!

Comment: @Anthony :D yes i shall delete this sentence

Comment: Your result with an input of 4 would be `4 4 4 4 5 6 7 8 9`. Is this your interpretation of what the original question was seeking?

Comment: If there input were changed to `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1 }` then I think the result (for 4 `{4, 5, 6}`) is different from what the OP is asking for (for 4 `{4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1}`).

Comment: @Anthony the output is in the image, sir; with the comments opened.

Comment: @Jeffrey I wrote this one for a sequential array of ints.

Comment: Then you could just do `Range(i, RowOfints[RowOfints.Length-1]-i).ToArray();` and ignore most of the input!

Comment: @Emre, oh, right, the Distinct eliminates the duplicates. There are better options, but keep exploring so you'll learn more.

Comment: @Jeffrey I dont really know that Range thing sir, I should google it.

Comment: Here's a link (to save you trouble of google :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx

Comment: @Jeffrey thank you so much, sir. I've got so much to learn :)

Comment: @Jeffrey sir it worked with this Range(i-1, RowOfints.Length + 1 - i).ToArray()

Answer (score -1):

using System.Linq;
....

```
int[] RowOfints = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int[] Answer = RowOfints.Where(x => x != 1 && x != 2 && x != 3).ToArray()
```

Comment: And if the array had 1,000 items in sequence and the requested index was 998?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but the OP specified that "4" was also part of the input, and it should be used in some way or other. You should try to squeeze it in somewhere.